# JSON Data changes while transferring from C# to ExtJS

Tags: c#, ajax, json, extjs

When transferring JSON data from a Webmethod in asp.net C# through an Ajax call in ExtJS 4.2.2, several characters are added to the beginning and end of the string.

JSON Data before leaving C#:

```
[{"ID":"0","NAME":"ALAN"},{"ID":"1","NAME":"BLAKE"}]
```

JSON Data as seen by firebug which is received by ExtJS

```
{"d":"[{"ID":"0","NAME":"ALAN"},{"ID":"1","NAME":"BLAKE"}]"}
```

This will also happen if the JSON Data has a set root property. 
From what it appears it seems as if something somewhere along the line treated the incoming data as a variable in a JSON string or something like that.

Code on the C# end:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "localhost")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Director : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true, XmlSerializeString = false)]
    public string getData()
    {
        string json = "[{\"ID\":\"0\",\"NAME\":\"ALAN\"},{\"ID\":\"1\",\"NAME\":\"BLAKE\"}]";
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(json);
        return json;
    }
}
```

Code for the ExtJS Ajax Call (already has a workaround implemented):

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    async: false,
    url: Test061014.ApplicationPath + '/Director.asmx/getData',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    scope: this,
    success: function (conn, response, options, eOpt) {
        var s = conn.responseText;
        s = s.substring(6, (s.length - 2));
        s = s.replace(/\\/g, "");
        categoryData = JSON.parse(s);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is inserted by ASP.NET for security reasons. Check out [this article](http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/) for more details.

> If you aren’t familiar with the “.d” I’m referring to, it is simply a
>   security feature that Microsoft added in ASP.NET 3.5’s version of
>   ASP.NET AJAX. By encapsulating the JSON response within a parent
>   object, the framework helps protect against a particularly nasty XSS
>   vulnerability.

They have a nice solution of using the `dataFilter` property so you can stop worrying about `.d`.  Again, credit to the article, here is their solution. You may need to read the article's **Don't make me think** section as there are a couple of details I left out.

```
dataFilter: function(data) {
// This boils the response string down 
//  into a proper JavaScript Object().
var msg = eval('(' + data + ')');

// If the response has a ".d" top-level property,
//  return what's below that instead.
if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d'))
  return msg.d;
else
  return msg;
},
```