# Javascript code getting while loop inserted

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I've found a very difficult-to-reproduce problem, but I thought someone here may have seen this.

In some Javascript code being executed, I have code with the following construct (using ExtJS)

```
var newObject = Ext.Object({
    property: 'value',
    property2: 'value',
    property3: new Ext.Object2({
        property1: 'value',
        listProperty: [
            { name: 'foo', value: 'bar' },
            { name2: 'foo2', value: 'bar2' }
        ]
    })
});
```

What's happening is, when executing this code in the browser, it appears something is attemping to do some data tainting to prevent JSON hijacking.  So the code, when you do a view source, looks like this

```
var newObject = Ext.Object({
    property: 'value',
    property2: 'value',
    property3: new Ext.Object2({
        property1: 'value',
        listProperty: F_O_O: while(1) {[
            { name: 'foo', value: 'bar' },
            { name2: 'foo2', value: 'bar2' }
            last F_O_O; }
        ]
    })
});
```

Unfortunately this is invalid JavaScript and result in a runtime error.

I have researched this extensively, as have several other developers, and we have been unable to definitively discover what is making this inline code change.  Many web searches have not revealed any specifics on who is inserting this code (Windows? IE? FF? Apache?).  We have seen the change happen in IE8, IE9, and Firefox.  This is Javascript code running via Apache 2.2 installed on a Windows 2008 R2 server, with Mason installed.

Has anyone else ever seen anything like this happen?

Comment: Apparently, it is common for frameworks to edit JSON to prevent hijacking. Similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147100/json-data-changes-while-transferring-from-c-sharp-to-extjs) where asp.net adds `d:` to the json string.

Comment: As a side note, what's with all the `Ext.Object` stuff?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I just used fake names instead of the real ExtJS objects.  The actual object giving me this issue is Ext.data.JsonReader.  http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonReader

Comment: If you want to work around it on the client side, you would need to write a custom reader that strips out all the cruft before running the json parser on it.